# Getting Rails to display development style errors in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, dreamhost

I deployed a Rails 3.0.3 app to my production server and it's giving me a 500 error.
This is being deployed on Dreamhost, so I looked in the logs for my domain and there is nothing and the logs for my app also show nothing.

How do I get Rails displaying actual error messages in production so I can sort this out?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try changing the `consider_all_requests_local` setting in `environments/production.rb`.

Comment: That was my thought as well, but I tried it and restarted my app and it still does not seem to work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Has it ever worked in production (is anything working)? If so, then I would probably evaluate recent changes. If not, and the log files aren't helping, then I would start with a simple test case, a "Hello World" app, and just try to get that running first.

Comment: No its a new app, but really its not much more than a Hello world. It even works if I SSH into the server and run the console in production mode!

Comment: Do you have other Rails apps running successfully on Dreamhost? Not being snarky, just wondering if this is a configuration issue particular to Dreamhost Rails deployments (in which case there may be some blog/newsgroup posts out there covering the gotchas).

Comment: Hey, I do have other apps running on DH, just not Rails 3 ones. This was was such a pain I hosted it on Heroku. It was up and running in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it was due to a bug in Aibrake in version 3.1.1.
Rollbacking to 3.0.9 solved the issue for me